# Elasticsearch - parsing query that uses curl command

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a query that runs from code (with an external library), and now I am trying to run it directly from the terminal, using the curl command:

This is the original query:

```
{
    "index": [
        "logstash-*2021.08.21*",
        "logstash-*2021.08.22*"
    ],
    "ignore_unavailable": true,
    "allow_no_indices": true,
    "type": "doc",
    "body": {
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [
                    {
                        "range": {
                            "@timestamp": {
                                "gte": "now-24H/H"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But running the folwing query from Linux terminal:

```
curl -u "*******:****************" -XGET "https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:9200/logstash- 
*/_search" 
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' 
-d '
 {
    "index": [
        "logstash-*2021.08.21*",
        "logstash-*2021.08.22*"
    ],
    "ignore_unavailable": true,
    "allow_no_indices": true,
    "type": "doc",
    "body": {
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [
                    {
                        "range": {
                            "@timestamp": {
                                "gte": "now-24H/H"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
'
```

returns error:

> {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"Unknown
> key for a START_ARRAY in
> [index].","line":1,"col":10}],"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"Unknown
> key for a START_ARRAY in [index].","line":1,"col":10},"status":4

It is worth noting that running the folwing query without additional parameters, returns correct results:

```
curl -u "elastic:****************" -XGET "https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:9200/logstash-*/_search"
```

What do I need to change in the terminal query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurrs because the search API does not specify an `indices` request body option.
Maybe your external library wraps the requests to Elasticsearch, hence you can provide this option.

With

```
-XGET "https://XXX:9200/logstash-*/_search"
```

you already specified that you want to search in all indices matching `logstash-*`.

Take a look at the documentation here for all possible request and url parameters: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-search.html

If you need to search multiple indices you need to follow the instructions in this guide: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multiple-indices.html

But since you already have provided an index-pattern in the URL, I don't know if this is still necessary.

**Also:**

There is no `body` and `type` fields allowed in the request body. So after removing the indices array these will be the next errors that Elasticsearch will complain about.

I hope I could help you.

Answer (score 0):

Using [apt-get-install-skill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11486670/apt-get-install-skill) tips, I changed the query to:

```
curl -u "*******:****************" -XGET --globoff "https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:9200/logstash-*2021.08.21*,logstash-*2021.08.22*/_search?ignore_unavailable=true&allow_no_indices=true" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{"query":{"range":{"@timestamp":{"gte":"now-24H/H"}}}}'
```

It works.
Thanks

Comment: Glad I could help you. Would you mind accepting my answer?

Comment: No, you upvoted the answer but not marked it as accepted via the tickmark ..